# Django excel save_book_to_database() broken in latest version using Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-excel

I've been going through the django excel documentation using Django 1.8, but haven't been able to get `save_book_to_database(...)` to work.

It either fails silently or gives the following error:

```
'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I have followed the syntax from the docs, but I have no idea why it keeps breaking or failing silently: http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: have you checked this? https://github.com/pyexcel/django-excel/issues/30

Comment: Yes, the "new" syntax mentioned in the post fails silently and the syntax in the latest docs returns the `'tuple' object has no attribute '_meta'` error

Comment: i think you should open an issue there

Comment: _meta is used [here, at pyexcel-io](https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-io/blob/master/pyexcel_io/database/django.py#L33). Are you using django-excel with other django extensions, which might modify django models?